# Exclude class from cross-project dependency via Gradle

Tags: android, build.gradle, unity-game-engine, buildconfig

I've recently upgraded to Unity 5.6 in hopes of utilizing the Gradle build pipeline (to workaround the nasty dex limit).

After some days of configuring it, I ran into this head-cracking issue. Here is the error as displayed in the Unity Editor console:

```
Execution failed for task ':transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: my/unity/game/BuildConfig.class
```

So it seems that some plugin/external project is including a BuildConfig class file with the exact same package name (as depicted by the file structure, and also why I had to set enforceUniquePackageName to false in the main project gradle).

In Android Studio, when looking for the BuildConfig file, I noticed two different projects that had the same package name. One of the projects was definitely for the main Unity project, while the other was for an automatically included project: unity-android-resources.

Is there a way I could somehow either:

- Exclude the BuildConfig.java from the automatically generated
  unity-android-resources project via the main gradle file? or,
- Is there someway I could alter the package name for the automatically
  generated BuildConfig.java file for unity-android-resources?

If it helps, here are the dependencies (and no, doesn't seem like I can just remove unity-android-resources dependency, as the build fails due to some missing icon resources):

```
dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile(name: 'GoogleAIDL', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'GooglePlay', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'appcompat-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'cardview-v7-23.4.0', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'common', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.0', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-ads-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-auth-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-auth-base-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-base-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-basement-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-drive-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-games-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-iid-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-nearby-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'play-services-tasks-10.0.1', ext:'aar')
     compile(name: 'support-v4-24.0.0', ext:'aar')
     compile project(':Etcetera_lib')
     compile project(':Flurry_lib')
     compile project(':MainLibProj')
     compile project(':PermissionCheckPlugin')
     compile project(':SwrvePush_lib')
     compile project(':fyber-unityads-1.5.6-r3')
     compile project(':unity-android-resources') // <- possible cause of error
}
```

Thanks for any help guys.

Comment: Are you importing Android Studio plugin into Unity or exporting it to Android Studio?